# Cannot query nodes

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graphql, cypher

This is the structure of my schema

```
type Process @query(read: true, aggregate: true) {
  material_id: String
  batch_id: String
  basic_mat: String
  happened: Date
}
```

Now, querying process returns an empty array

```
query Processes($where: ProcessWhere) {
  processes(where: $where) {
    basic_mat
    material_id
    batch_id
  }
}
```

This is the variable where

```
{ 
  "where": {
    "batch_id": "abc101"
  }
}
```

I went further to enable debug and this is what I get

```
  @neo4j/graphql:auth using JWT provided in context: undefined +0ms
  @neo4j/graphql:execution executing cypher +0ms
  @neo4j/graphql:execution CALL dbms.components() YIELD versions, edition UNWIND versions AS version RETURN version, edition +1ms
  @neo4j/graphql:execution cypher params: {} +0ms
  @neo4j/graphql:translate ReadOperation
  @neo4j/graphql:translate |──── PropertyFilter [batch_id] <EQ>
  @neo4j/graphql:translate |──── AttributeField <basic_mat>
  @neo4j/graphql:translate |──── AttributeField <material_id>
  @neo4j/graphql:translate |──── AttributeField <batch_id> +0ms
  @neo4j/graphql:execution executing cypher +655ms
  @neo4j/graphql:execution MATCH (this:Process)
  @neo4j/graphql:execution WHERE this.batch_id = $param0
  @neo4j/graphql:execution RETURN this { .basic_mat, .material_id, .batch_id } AS this +0ms
  @neo4j/graphql:execution cypher params: { param0: 'abc101' } +0ms
  @neo4j/graphql:execution Execute successful, received 0 records +0ms
```

running this cypher in neo4j returns values but not when I am using the neo4j/graphql lib.
any Idea what the issue is here

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,

Needed to add this to context

```
 sessionConfig: { database: "myNeoGraph" }
```